# [ROS2] Is there a function to obtain message size of a ROS2 message in C++?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This could be useful when optimizing system performance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329570/%5Bros2%5D-is-there-a-function-to-obtain-message-size-of-a-ros2-message-in-c++?/) by [ahtsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43242/ahtsan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2019-07-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2019-07-31**:
By size, do you mean the size of a message once it it serialized?

**Comment by [ahtsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43242/ahtsan/) on 2019-07-31**:
Yes, if that means the same as the throughput of a publisher if the publisher published that message.

**Comment by [ahtsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43242/ahtsan/) on 2019-08-01**:
Just want to confirm: Is it not possible at this stage? Will it be supported later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently there is no API to determine the wire size of a message. And it isn't planned to implement that feature.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1